# df fluctuates badly

Tags: disk-usage, usb-drive, external-hdd

I ran `df -h` several times in rapid succession, and I'm getting these results.  Can somebody help me understand why?

I'm not sure how much back-story you need.  The disk in question is a Toshiba DT01ABA300 external USB hard drive which I am currently using for backups.  But I'm not adding and removing GB of files, I'm just running a backup which should primarily (if not **only**) be adding data to the disk.

```
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.1T  517G  81% /storage  
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.1T  466G  83% /storage  
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.3T  261G  91% /storage  
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.2T  363G  87% /storage  
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.1T  517G  81% /storage  
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.3T  312G  89% /storage  
$ df -h /storage
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdi1             2.7T  2.1T  466G  83% /storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information is impossible to tell what's happening. What you can do is:

1. Prepend your `df` command with `date` so you can know how fast the free disk space is changing. I'm surprised, in particular, by the rapid delete/write of 200 Gb.
2. Use `du` to check disk usage in subdirs of `/storage`.
3. Do a `lsof | grep storage` to see which process is opening files in your `/storage`.

Comment: *"Use df to check disk usage in subdirs of /storage."* That won't work unless they are separate file systems; OP wants `du` in that case.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You're absolutely right, corrected.